# Can Safari play reverse css3 animations?

Tags: css, animation, safari, reverse

Correct me if I am wrong, but I have to notice that reverse animations do not work in Safari. I was not the first to ask about this, but since I did not yet find the answer, I posted this question.

Is there any way to make reversed animations work in Safari? ...or should I just forget about them?

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
div{
Background-color: red;
font-size:2vw;
position:fixed;
top:40%;
right:0%;
width:100%;
height:12%;
/*animation*/
-webkit-animation:test_drive 5s;
   -moz-animation:test_drive 5s;
    -ms-animation:test_drive 5s;
     -o-animation:test_drive 5s;
        animation:test_drive 5s;
/*animation-direction*/
-webkit-animation-direction:reverse;
   -moz-animation-direction:reverse;
    -ms-animation-direction:reverse;
     -o-animation-direction:reverse;
        animation-direction:reverse;
z-index:3;
}
@-webkit-keyframes test_drive{
0%   {left:0%; top:40%;}
100% {left:0%; top:88%;}
}
@-ms-keyframes test_drive{
0%   {left:0%; top:40%;}
100% {left:0%; top:88%;}
}
@-moz-keyframes test_drive{
0%   {left:0%; top:40%;}
100% {left:0%; top:88%;}
}
@-o-keyframes test_drive{
0%   {left:0%; top:40%;}
100% {left:0%; top:88%;}
}
@keyframes test_drive{
0%   {left:0%; top:40%;}
100% {left:0%; top:88%;}
}
</style>
<title>Test_Drive</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>Unlike Chrome, Firefox, Opera or IE, Safari plays this in "normal" direction.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes in your code. Please take a look at the code given below. It is working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
div{
Background-color: red;
font-size:2vw;
position:fixed;
top:40%;
right:0%;
width:100%;
height:12%;
/*animation*/
-webkit-animation:test_drive 5s;
   -moz-animation:test_drive 5s;
    -ms-animation:test_drive 5s;
     -o-animation:test_drive 5s;
        animation:test_drive 5s;
/*animation-direction*/
-webkit-animation-direction:normal;
   -moz-animation-direction:reverse;
    -ms-animation-direction:reverse;
     -o-animation-direction:reverse;
        animation-direction:reverse;
z-index:3;
}
@-webkit-keyframes test_drive{
0%   {left:0%; top:88%;}
100% {left:0%; top:40%;}
}
@-ms-keyframes test_drive{
0%   {left:0%; top:40%;}
100% {left:0%; top:88%;}
}
@-moz-keyframes test_drive{
0%   {left:0%; top:40%;}
100% {left:0%; top:88%;}
}
@-o-keyframes test_drive{
0%   {left:0%; top:40%;}
100% {left:0%; top:88%;}
}
@keyframes test_drive{
0%   {left:0%; top:40%;}
100% {left:0%; top:88%;}
}
</style>
<title>Test_Drive</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>Unlike Chrome, Firefox, Opera or IE, Safari plays this in "normal" direction.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Still, I don't understand why it actualy worked. Every browser plays it as it was reversed.

Comment: You voted but my mistake I clicked down arrow so lost the reputation. Could you please do it again.

Comment: I set -webkit-animation-direction to 'normal', and I interchanged top values in @-webkit-keyframes test_drive to make it work for Safari. In IE, Mozilla, Chrome your code was already working. Code changed by me corresponds to Chrome and Safari.

Comment: This suite says that Opera does not support reverse also. Should I do the same for -o- ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Yes, you can do the same for -o-.

Comment: It is working fine for Opera as well. You can remove opera related lines from your code. (-webkit-animation-direction will work for Chrome, Safari and Opera).

Answer (score 2):

From the [Safari Developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/internetweb/conceptual/safarivisualeffectsprogguide/AnimatingWithKeyframes/AnimatingWithKeyframes.html), Safari supports `-webkit-animation-direction` with values of `normal` (default) or `alternate`. It does not support `reverse`.

> **-webkit-animation-direction:** Causes repeating animation to either proceed in the same direction each time or to alternate directions.
>   Can be set to normal (default) or alternate. If set to alternate, the
>   animation goes forward and backward—from 0% to 100% and from 100% to
>   0%—on alternate iterations. The webkit-animation-iteration-count value
>   must be greater than one1 for this property to have any effect.

Comment: Also see the [Mozilla Developer Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction#Browser_compatibility) for more information about browser compatibility.